# Maven dependency for Teradata JDBC driver

Tags: maven, jdbc, dependency-management, teradata

Does Teradata have its JDBC driver uploaded as a jar referenced from a maven file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with Oracle drivers, closed source dependencies aren't usually hosted on open source repositories. You can install it in your local repository or use something like Nexus to do the job for your team/company.

Answer (score 4):

Do below step

1. Download Teradata Jar from [link](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver)

   > - terajdbc4.jar
   > - tdgssconfig.jar
2. Move downloaded jars to a directory. For example : D://lib
3. open Command Prompt(CMD) and go to directory (D://lib)
4. execute below command

   > - mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.teradata.jdbc -DartifactId=tdgssconfig -Dversion=14.00.00.21 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=tdgssconfig.jar
   > - mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.teradata.jdbc -DartifactId=terajdbc4 -Dversion=14.00.00.21 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=terajdbc4.jar
5. Update POM.xml with below dependencies

   com.teradata.jdbc
       terajdbc4
       14.00.00.21


       com.teradata.jdbc
       tdgssconfig
       14.00.00.21

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking the same as you, and wasn't found in http://mvnrepository.com/tags/jdbc

Please Take a look at this URL :
http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver

**Sample code :**

```
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
String connectionString = "jdbc:teradata://MyDatabaseServer/database=MyDatabaseName,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8";
String user = "username";
String passwd = "password";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, password);
```

You should have both of the following jars in your classpath

> terajdbc4.jar
>
> tdgssconfig.jar

Answer (score 3):

The latest Teradata JDBC driver (16.20.00.12) release note has the following statement:

> This release includes changes to address the following issues, originally included
>   in release 16.20.00.11:
>
> JDBC-191761 Eliminate tdgssconfig.jar

Hence we just need to install "terajdbc4.jar".

Following the similar steps provided by @Swarit, download the latest from [teradata downloads](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver), the current version is "16.20.00.12", install the "terajdbc4.jar" into local maven repo:

> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.teradata.jdbc -Dartifa
>   ctId=terajdbc4 -Dversion=16.20.00.12 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=terajdbc4.jar

And then you can specify the dependency in your POM file as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>16.20.00.12</version>
</dependency>
```